# Why does the memory consumption of a dictionary increase when 64 bit hashes are used instead of strings?

Tags: c#, dictionary

We use dictionaries in various places in the existing code, where we map tags to objects that each contain that tag. This was never a problem before, as these dictionaries "only" managed several thousand objects. However, we are now at a point with the software where we are more likely to be dealing with tens to hundreds of thousands of objects. The use of the said tag as a key leads to the fact that we consume a lot of unnecessary memory, because these tags are stored twice and can reach lengths of more than 150 characters.

So the idea was obvious to replace the long tags with a hash that has a fixed size. For this we decided to use the FNV hash algorithm, which calculates an unsigned 64-bit integer from the string. To avoid having to make too many changes to the existing code, we enclosed the dictionary in an object that converts the passed string keys and works on an internal dictionary. This saves us masses of changes in the methods that use the previous implementation. You could call it a decorator in the broadest sense. The following is a brief outline of what we came up with.

```cs
[Serializable]
public class SimpleTestObject {

    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public SimpleTestObject(string tag) {
        this.Tag = tag;
    }
}


[Serializable]
public class FnvDictionary<T> : IDictionary<string, T> where T : SimpleTestObject {
    private ConcurrentDictionary<UInt64, T> _InternalDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<UInt64, T>();

    public T this[string key] {
        get {
            return this._InternalDictionary[this.CalculateHash(key)];
        }
        set {
            if (key != value.Tag)
                throw new ArgumentException();
            _InternalDictionary[this.CalculateHash(key)] = value;
        }
    }

    public ICollection<string> Keys {
        get { return this._InternalDictionary.Values.Select(item => item.Tag).ToList(); }
    }

    public ICollection<T> Values {
        get { return this._InternalDictionary.Values; }
    }

    public int Count {
        get { return this._InternalDictionary.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly {
        get { return false; }
    }
    public void Add(string key, T value) {
        this._InternalDictionary[this.CalculateHash(key)] = value;
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, T> item) {
        this.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public void Clear() {
        this._InternalDictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, T> item) {
        if (item.Key != item.Value.Tag)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        return this.ContainsKey(item.Value.Tag);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key) {
        return this._InternalDictionary.ContainsKey(CalculateHash(key));
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, T>[] array, int arrayIndex) {
        KeyValuePair<string, T>[] source = this._InternalDictionary
            .Select(data => new KeyValuePair<string, T>(data.Value.Tag, data.Value))
            .ToArray();
        Array.Copy(source, 0, array, arrayIndex, source.Length);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, T>> GetEnumerator() {
        return new FnvDictionaryEnumerator<T>(this._InternalDictionary);
    }

    public bool Remove(string key) {
        return this._InternalDictionary.TryRemove(this.CalculateHash(key), out _);
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, T> item) {
        return this.Remove(item.Value.Tag);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out T value) {
        return this._InternalDictionary.TryGetValue(this.CalculateHash(key), out value);
    }

    private UInt64 CalculateHash(string input) {
        const UInt64 MAGIC_PRIME = 1099511628211;
        UInt64 hash = 14695981039346656037;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            hash = (hash ^ (byte)input[i]) * MAGIC_PRIME;

        return hash;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class FnvDictionaryEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, T>> where T : SimpleTestObject {
    private ConcurrentDictionary<UInt64, T> _InternalDictionary;
    private readonly int _KeysCount;
    private int _KeyPos;

    public FnvDictionaryEnumerator(ConcurrentDictionary<UInt64, T> data) {
        _InternalDictionary = data;
        _KeysCount = data.Keys.Count;
        _KeyPos = -1;
    }

    public KeyValuePair<string, T> Current {
        get {
            T currentItem = _InternalDictionary.ElementAt(_KeyPos).Value;
            return new KeyValuePair<string, T>(currentItem.Tag, currentItem);
        }
    }

    object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current => this.Current;

    public bool MoveNext() => ++_KeyPos < _KeysCount;

    public void Reset() => _KeyPos = -1;

    public void Dispose() {
        _InternalDictionary = null;
    }
}
```

Now to the problem: The object described above was examined by us with a small test program and compared directly with the ConcurrentDictionary used so far. For this we have built a small function that outputs the size of the respective dictionaries:

```cs
public static long GetObjectSize(object source) {
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
        return stream.Length;
    }
}
```

After we had created 250000 data sets on a test basis and packed them into the dictionaries, we were disillusioned. Although our own creation works exclusively with hashes that are each 8 bytes long, the memory consumption is higher than in the ConcurrentDictionary.

```cs
const string TAG_BASE = "XXXXX|XXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXX-";
const int TEST_OBJECTS_COUNT = 250000;

SimpleTestObject[] testObjects = new SimpleTestObject[TEST_OBJECTS_COUNT];
for (int index = 0; index < testObjects.Length; index++)
    testObjects[index] = new SimpleTestObject($"{TAG_BASE}{index}");
    
ConcurrentDictionary<string, SimpleTestObject> concurrentDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SimpleTestObject>();
foreach (SimpleTestObject testObject in testObjects)
    concurrentDict[testObject.Tag] = testObject;
    
Console.WriteLine("Size of the ConcurrentDictionary = {0} bytes.", GetObjectSize(concurrentDict));

FnvDictionary<SimpleTestObject> customDict = new FnvDictionary<SimpleTestObject>();
foreach (SimpleTestObject testObject in testObjects)
    customDict.Add(testObject.Tag, testObject);

Console.WriteLine("Size of the FnvDictionary = {0} bytes.", GetObjectSize(customDict));


// Output:
// Size of the ConcurrentDictionary = 36140494 bytes.
// Size of the custom dictionary = 36890908 bytes.
```

The question that now arises is how it can be that a dictionary that supposedly holds less data can have a larger memory consumption. The assumption is obvious that the ConcurrentDictionary also works only on the basis of hashes, but this is contradicted by the fact that the collection of keys can be retrieved continuously. Is there a design problem in the test scenario described above or even in the GetObjectSize function? And more important: How can the memory consumption of the dictionary be reduced as much as possible?

Comment: The two for loops are not the same 1) No ADD : concurrentDict[testObject.Tag] = testObject; 2) ADD : customDict.Add(testObject.Tag, testObject);

Comment: Surely, the dictionary isn't holding less data? Each item still contains the key, but now it's stored in the `Tag` property. However you've additionally gained an extra 8 bytes for your new `UInt64` key

Comment: `Premature optimization is the root of all evil`. Why use dictionaries instead of a database? A single-threaded, single-index Dictionary is never going to be as fast as a database server with multiple cores, fast RAM and multiple indexes to choose from.

Comment: Binary serialization is not at all a correct indication of actual memory consumption. Use proper benchmarks like benchmarkdotnet, memory profilers or a simple `GC.Collect(); GC.GetTotalMemory()` for a rougher approximation. In either scenario the strings themselves probably consume the most memory -- this is true even when you're hashing them, since they still have to be generated first, and actually storing them multiple times takes no more than 4 or 8 bytes (depending on bitness) since they're references.

Comment: Remember that strings in .NET are reference types: the actual string data is stored in a heap-allocated object, and any type which has a `string` field just has a pointer-sized reference to that object. So if you reference a single string object from 2 places, the cost is the size of the string heap object, plus `2 * (word size)` (where the word size is 4 bytes for x86, 8 bytes for x64). So storing the same string twice costs an extra 4 bytes on x86.

Comment: Also remember that dictionaries already organise themselves using a hash code, but they do so using a 32-bit hash code. You've added an additional 64-bit hash code which the dictionary needs to store, but it still condenses it down into a 32-bit hash code internally. You've just given it another, new hash code to worry about, while also opening yourself up to hash code collisions.

Comment: The fact that you've only gained 3 bytes per entry is remarkable, and shows that your memory-measuring technique is floored (most likely due to optimisations that `BinaryFormatter` is doing for you, see @JeroenMostert's comment). It should be an additional 4 bytes per entry at least.

Comment: I will try with benchmarkdotnet `MemoryDiagnoser` at least in order to get visibility. https://adamsitnik.com/the-new-Memory-Diagnoser/

Comment: The memory usage analysis is roughly correct.  System.String is a reference type, the Tag property and the key in the dictionary takes 32 bits of storage in 32-bit mode, 64 bits in x64.  So you replaced (up to) 64 bits with a 64 integer, no improvement.  Worse actually, you have no guarantee that the hash is unique to properly operate as the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Remember that strings in .NET are reference types: the actual string
> data is stored in a heap-allocated object, and any type which has a
> string field just has a pointer-sized reference to that object.
> [canton7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66966130/why-does-the-memory-consumption-of-a-dictionary-increase-when-64-bit-hashes-are#comment118371585_66966130)

I didn't realize that before. I assumed that strings are value types. To investigate this aspect in more detail, I got myself a Visual Studio Enterprise installation, since it has memory analysis tools. With a small test program, the behavior was easy to observe. In the code in the following example, a value type would cause the dictionary to be twice as large as the list. This is not the case.

```cs
const string TAG_BASE = "XXXXX|XXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXX-";
const int TEST_OBJECTS_COUNT = 250000;

List<string> myList = new List<string>();
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for (int index = 0; index < TEST_OBJECTS_COUNT; index++)
{
    string myString = TAG_BASE + index;
    myList.Add(myString);
    myDictionary.Add(myString, myString);
}
```

The result was already predicted to me in the comments:

> Also remember that dictionaries already organise themselves using a
> hash code, but they do so using a 32-bit hash code. You've added an
> additional 64-bit hash code which the dictionary needs to store, but
> it still condenses it down into a 32-bit hash code internally. You've
> just given it another, new hash code to worry about, while also
> opening yourself up to hash code collisions.
> [canton7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66966130/why-does-the-memory-consumption-of-a-dictionary-increase-when-64-bit-hashes-are#comment118371585_66966130)

When analyzing the memory dump, it became clear quite quickly that the strings are indeed stored as references. Thus, our well-intentioned approach only worsens the problem by forcing the memory management to store another numeric value instead of the actually used references, which in turn has to be calculated again.

In fact, in the example described above, both collections consume about the same amount of memory. In the case of the dictionary, there is also some administrative overhead.

| Object type | Size (Bytes) |
| --- | --- |
| Dictionary<string, string> | 65,448,420 |
| List<string> | 60,007,980 |

**To answer my question:** Memory consumption is increasing because we are unintentionally forcing it to do so. The reason for this is insufficient knowledge about internal memory management. For the future: *Rely on analysis tools instead of self-builds!*

Thanks to all the commenters for the important advice!

Comment: I highly recommend you read the Jeffrey Richter book, this question is a good case in point, another is a Joel Spoolsky story "Shlemiel gets a job as a street painter": https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm?

Comment: For everyone who's interested [this is the original post of Joel Spoolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). But which Jeffrey Richter book do you mean exactly?

Comment: I was lucky enough to get a 6 month mentorship while doing Microsoft Dev support. And it's the **CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter** that I had to master to pass the training. As a result if I see like string concatenation in a for loop I'll shudder, additionally if I see undisposed unmanaged objects or lots of boxing/unboxing I have the underlying knowledge to understand the what's happening in the CLR, Managed Heap, Thread Stack and how to use optimal types.